# stack variable or declaration of function

Tags: c++, linux, g++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

I have two classes in file1.h:

```
class ZoneRecord {
public:
    //a lof of stuff here
};

class RegisterRecord {
public:
RegisterRecord(ZoneRecord rec); //this function register object rec in a fabric
};
```

And file2.cpp has:

```
#include "file1.h"
class MockZoneRecord: public ZoneRecord {
public:
MockZoneRecord(): ZoneRecord() {}
};

RegisterRecord mockrecord_register(MockZoneRecord());
```

This code compiles perfectly, except one thing. It says that mockrecord_register is a declaration of a function. But I actually wanted to create an global object of type RegisterRecord with name mockrecord_register. How to explicitly tell to compiler that this is not a function prototype, but an object?

Comment: just out of fun, do u get this warning if u declared this object inside a main()?

Comment: Wrap the argument in `()`: `mockrecord_register((MockZoneRecord()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are experiencing the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

One way to solve this is to use copying, like

```
RegisterRecord mockrecord_register = RegisterRecord(MockZoneRecord());
```

Another is the use of parenthesis like in the answer by yuri kilochek.

If your compiler is C++11 compatible, you could use this construct:

```
RegisterRecord mockrecord_register{MockZoneRecord()};
```

Answer (score 1):

Place parenthesis around argument:

```
RegisterRecord mockrecord_register((MockZoneRecord()));
```